# SonarQube Code Profiling and Static Code Analysis

Tags: sonarqube, profiling

I need to setup SonarQube for static analysis of my code. There is also a requirement of profiling of the code. I am new to this area and have questions on these.

As I have learned that,

**SonarQube** is a central server that processes full analyses (triggered by the various SonarQube Scanners). Its purpose is to give a 360° vision of the quality of your code base. For this, it analyzes all the source lines of your project on a regular basis.

**Code profilers** are used by developers to help identify performance problems. Profilers also track things like memory allocations and garbage collection.

In **Visual Studio** there are two separate functionalities for code profiling (in debug section) and code analysis (Analyze section).

I think code profiling and static code analysis are different. I might be wrong also. Can anyone please let me know on this?
Can SonarQube  be used as a code profiler in parallal as static code analysis?

Any guidance on this is really appreciable.

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question. SonarQube is not a profiler, in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr thank you for confirming.